# Не получается получить доступ к сайту по внешнему айпи

Tags: c#, windows, .net, ubuntu, localhost

Запускаю приложение aps.net core 3.1 как консольное приложение.
По localhost подключаюсь получаю строку.
При попытке открыть сайт уже по статическому апи(купил у дом ру). Страница не найдена.

Что пробовал:

1. Подключал через роутер пробрасывал порты, отключал фаервол, включал
   dmz.
2. Открывал порты в Брандмауэре Винды.
3. Отключал Брандмауэр Винды.
4. Подключал эзернет от провайдера минуя роутер напрямую к пк.
5. Переустанавливал ось.
6. Запускал на Windows 10 и Ubuntu.
7. Пробовал на разных пк.

П.С. Раньше всё работало, но справедливости ради с тех пор когда я последний раз это делал я менял роутер.

Comment: Исходя из всего перечисленного, можно понять только то, что ни C#, ни ASP.NET Core здесь не при чем. Пингуйте, кидайте трассировки, играйте шрифтами (с бубном). Более конкретных советов дать практически невозможно. Проблема может быть вызвана примерно чем угодно (но это не точно). Ну и проверьте, а тот IP, куда вы пробрасываете порты действительно ли совпадает с адресом компа, где у вас сервак.

Comment: насчёт последнего, я же напрямую к пк эзернет подключал и проблема осталась :(

Comment: Это ничего не объясняет.

Comment: эзернет провайдера не так выразился

Comment: Лучше обратитесь к специалисту, который продиагностирует проблему и исправит. Здесь мы только в угадайку поиграть сможем.

Comment: Если подскажете где можно найти специалиста буду благодарен

Comment: а с какими параметрами вы запускаете приложение, вы можете привязывать ваше приложение только на localhost (если в логал написано, например, localhost:5000), тогда оно и не будет доступно из внешней сети, нужно привязывать ко всем сетевым интерфейсам, как-то так http://+:5000

Comment: я тебя обожаю, даже в голову не пришло, в appsettings прописал  "urls": "http://+:5000" и заработало

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, Exploding Kitten. В appsettings прописал  "urls": "http://+:5000" и заработало.

Comment: `Раньше всё работало` если бы вы не написали вот это, я бы почти сразу вам посоветовал именно этот способ. А так получалось, что у вас сервер нормально настроен, но потом вы поменяли роутер и все сломалось.